# how to make even gap for overall card in flexlayoutgap

Tags: flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I tried to make a responsive card layout with even gap between each card , unfortunately bottom space not coming on card, but right side gap showing , can any one help how to achieve this scenario. below is my code

**Html Code**

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" fxLayoutGap="25px">
  <mat-card *ngFor="let member of members" fxFlex="calc(33%-25px)" fxFlex.sm="calc(50%-25px)" >
```

**stack-blitz link**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/card-responsive?file=app/card-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the `fxLayout="row wrap"` functionality.  the suggestion from the doc says to use `fxLayoutGap="10px grid"`but this works even less.

I have come up with this css3 which solved your problem.  not very elegant, flex-layout-wise but this seem like a limitation

```
mat-card.mat-card { 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```